# how do you make a makefile

Tags: makefile

I would like to know how to makefile for Unix.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a good [Makefile Tutorial](http://oucsace.cs.ohiou.edu/~bhumphre/makefile.html) (first result on Google after searching "how to create a makefile").

Answer (score 3):

Because (g)make has many non-intuitive aspects, e.g. its backward chaining, I'd highly recommend having a look at Robert Mecklenburg's book [*Managing Projects with GNU Make*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596006101).

Or even better is Andrew Talbot's [*Managing Projects with Make*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00008CM4C) (second edition), which I feel has the better introduction to make. (IMHO naturally).

Answer (score 1):

http://www.opussoftware.com/tutorial/TutMakefile.htm

Answer (score 1):

Run make. ;)

Though you'd be better served by reading the make documentation. Do this by typing 'man make' from the command line. It should be enough to get you started and confused, at which point a Google search will help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The [Gnu make manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) would be a good place to look.

Answer (score 1):

I have compiled some notes here: http://ustunozgur.blogspot.com/2008/04/sample-makefile.html

Answer (score 0):

can check out [documentation](http://sources.redhat.com/autobook/autobook/autobook_toc.html) on automake (which most unix-y projects use) as well

Comment: I'd recommend against this until, the asker can at least read a makefile with confidence... the autotools are ugly.